# Referring dependency jar locally in Maven

Tags: maven, jar

In my project, I am using an external jar which is not present in company's Maven repository. So I am getting the following error

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project.Could not find artifact in http://company-name/maven2
```

Is there any way in which this jar can be referenced locally as workaround till company add that jar in its repository. Like if I create lib folder and put jar in that folder. Can I ask Maven to take jar from that lib folder instead of downloading from maven repository?

Answer (score 1):

You need [install:install-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html), which installs a copy of the JAR into your local `.m2/repository` which your POM can then depend on.

Comment: After using above command, I can see the required jar in my maven-repo. But when I use mvn install to compile project, getting same error, mvn is still referring to http:company-name/maven2

Comment: Please check the groupId-artifactId-version in the pom for the required jar in your local maven-repo matches the referring <dependency/>

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to recur to the utility [AddJars Maven Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/addjars-maven-plugin), available on Google Code. Henceforth, the simplest way to include a jar is to store it in a subfolder, say `lib`, located inside of your Maven project.

Then in your pom.xml simply add:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-jars</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/lib</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

There is more about plugin configuration [here](https://code.google.com/p/addjars-maven-plugin/wiki/UsagePage). In particular some additional steps are required under NetBeans to enable autocompletion.

Unfortunately this **requires Maven version 3.0.3 or higher**.