# ImageJ (fiji) compiling plugin

Tags: java, image-processing, java-3d, imagej

I am developing a plugin for ImageJ (fiji), I followed this tutorial to configure fiji for eclipse.

http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Developing_Fiji_in_Eclipse

Now I am working with the 3D ImageJ Suite and specifically the 3DRoiManager, but I cannot get the plugins to compile in Eclipse using the methodology described in the above tutorial.

Each plugin should have a pom.xml file, I think. Can anyone help me to make the 3DRoiManager run in imageJ from eclipse. Thank you

http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=plugin:stacks:3d_ij_suite:start

Comment: Adding non mavenized dependencies to maven project is a pain. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17090672/1903534 or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2230464/1903534

Comment: Since you tried to _compile_ 3DRoiManager, I understand that you want to use it not only as a dependency, but develop with it. I suggest to mavenize the sources of this plugin; you might want to take the [minimal ImageJ1 plugin](https://github.com/imagej/minimal-ij1-plugin) as a starting point and follow the instructions in its README.md

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the advice. I think I do not fully understand the idea of Mavern dependencies so I will do some research. I am looking to develop on 3DRoiManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to actually load the Fiji source code into Eclipse (which is what the "Developing Fiji in Eclipse" article is about). Rather, you are trying to develop an external ImageJ plugin: the 3D RoiManager. I agree that it is convenient to create a Maven project for it, so that you can easily develop the project in Eclipse, pull in other dependencies, etc.

I suggest using this project as a starting point: https://github.com/imagej/minimal-ij1-plugin

For more information, see this page: http://fiji.sc/Maven

Comment: I will have a go with the minimal project and hopefully get the 3DRoiManager working. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I managed to get 3DRoiManager working using the correct mavern dependencies. Thanks for the advice